# Cannot access UV: Squares despite it being enabled on Blender 3.0

Tags: uv

I am going through the Blender Guru donut tutorial. I'm stuck on Part 5, Level 3: Condensation at the 9:30 mark. The issue I am having is that I have installed UV: Squares on my computer and it seems to be enabled in Blender, but I can't find the toolbar. I've spent hours working this out and I am very confused. Please Help

[image]

[image]

Comment: That tutorial is for Blender version 2.83. If you're using Blender 3.0 or above you should be using the donut tutorial which has been completely rewritten for version 3.0. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD

Comment: Looking at your Preferences image you appear to have two entries for the addon which may be confusing Blender. Try removing one of them and try again.